# SQL_Add constraint and check the string using LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL.
Here is the table rental, and the CC_Type column means the credit card type. After creating the table, I want to add a constraint to make sure the credit card is either 'credit' or 'debit'

```
 CREATE TABLE rental
( Rental_Num       VARCHAR2(5)  CONSTRAINT rental_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Rent_Date        DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  Credit_Card_Num  CHAR(16),
  CC_Type          CHAR(7),
  Member_ID        VARCHAR2(5)
);
```

Therefore, I try to write:

```
ALTER TABLE RENTAL
  2  ADD CONSTRAINT CC_TYPE_CK
  3  CHECK(CC_TYPE LIKE 'Credit' OR CC_TYPE LIKE 'Debit');
```

But SQL yield:  cannot validate (SYSTEM.CC_TYPE_CK) - check constraint violated

I don't understand it violated what? And how to fix it?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently have data in the table that violates the constraint.  Your code basically works; [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=189414f46b412becae2ec596bce6d990) is a db<>fiddle (this fixes the extra comma before the closing paren in the create table statement).

So, look for the bad data:

```
select r.*
from rental r
where r.cc_type not in ('Credit', 'Debit');
```

I would also write the constraint using `in` . . . it is simpler:

```
ALTER TABLE RENTAL
    ADD CONSTRAINT CC_TYPE_CK
    CHECK (CC_TYPE IN ('Credit', 'Debit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove , after `Member_ID        VARCHAR2(5)` other wise your query working fine

```
CREATE TABLE rental
    ( Rental_Num       VARCHAR2(5)  CONSTRAINT rental_PK PRIMARY KEY,
      Rent_Date        DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
      Credit_Card_Num  CHAR(16),
      CC_Type          CHAR(7),
      Member_ID        VARCHAR2(5)

    );

    ALTER TABLE RENTAL
        ADD CONSTRAINT CC_TYPE_CK
       CHECK(CC_TYPE LIKE 'Credit' OR CC_TYPE LIKE 'Debit');
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72cea34a0f013041bb16b54abb1110ba)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gordon Linoff, Check for the data in cc_type.

```
select Distinct r.cc_type
from rental r;
```

If you still want to create the constraint even when you have the other CC_TYPEs(in the other words, without validating the existing data) then try this

```
ALTER TABLE RENTAL
    ADD CONSTRAINT CC_TYPE_CK
    CHECK (CC_TYPE IN ('Credit', 'Debit')) NOVALIDATE;
```